# OleDB INSERT STATEMENT Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I'm working on a project where I'm going to add records in database. My big problem is the "INSERT INTO" statement, after searching and debugging still no success. This is a part of the code:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click


    Dim sqlinsert As String = "INSERT INTO tblList([Access Number],[Book Title],Subject,Author,Edition,Page,Publisher,Years,Copy)" & "VALUES(@Access Number,@Book Title,@Subject,@Author,@Edition,@Page,@Publisher,@Years,@Copy)"

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Access Number", txtan.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Book Title", txtbt.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Subject", txtsub.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Author", txtau.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Edition", txted.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Page", txtpg.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Publisher", txtpub.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Years", txtyr.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Copy", txtco.Text))



    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("One Record Added")

    Refreshlist()
    clear()

End Sub
```

Help me please? I am so confused.
Thanks a lot. 
(A am using ms access and vb.net in visual studio 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon digging on some of my old programs, this is how I pass parameters to ms access:

```
Dim sqlinsert As String= "INSERT INTO tblList([Access Number],[Book Title],Subject,Author,Edition,Page,Publisher,Years,Copy)" & _
                         "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"  
        Dim cmd as new OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con)
        cmd.Connection.Open
        With cmd.Parameters
           .AddWithValue("access_number", txtan.text)
           .AddWithValue("book_title", txtbt.text)
           .AddWithValue("subject", txtsub.text)
           .AddWithValue("author", txtau.text)
           .AddWithValue("edition", txted.text)
           .AddWithValue("page", txtpg.text)
           .AddWithValue("publisher", txtpub.text)
           .AddWithValue("years", txtyr.text)
           .AddWithValue("copy", txtco.text)
        End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Also, I'd be wary of using `spaces` on your column names,
 specifically on `Access Number` and `Book Title`

P.S.

```
.AddWithValue("a", b)
```

a = this can be anything but as a personal rule of mine, i tend to name it based on the column name
b = the value you want to pass

Comment: Thnks for reply sir but it seems i cant let the txtpage,txtco and txtyr empty if i do there will be an error in cmd.executeninqeury() "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: verify if the data you are entering matches the data required by the field. if the field requires an integer, pass val(txtco.text) instead.

Comment: glad to be of help, dont forget the best answer tag :)

Answer (score 1):

Try change the name of these parameters from

- "@Access Number" to: "@Access_Number"
- "@Book Title" to: "@Book_Title"

Comment: thnks sir for the info. added info. to me